# ATmega328A UART: everything working, but not as expected

Tags: avr, atmega, uart, atmel

I am trying to get UART working via the ATmega328A. I want to enter a character, and get that character to be printed out. However, when my code is run this is what happens:

1. I enter one character, that character is printed out.
2. I enter a second character, and the character is printed out,But then the
   first character is printed out continuously, forever.

For example, the output from the console.

`<user input a 5><5 is printed><system waits for input><user enter a 3><three is printed><system prints 5 repeatedly(for ever)>`

[image]

The code:

```
 #include <avr/io.h>
 #include <util/delay.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
                                                      // include LCD library
  #define F_CPU 8000000UL       
 #define BAUD 9600                                                       // define baud
 #define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU)/(BAUD*16UL)-1)        // set baudrate value for UBRR


                                 // set the CPU clock


 // function to initialize UART
 void uart_init (void)
 {
     UBRR0H=(BAUDRATE>>8);
     UBRR0L=BAUDRATE;                                                 //set baud rate
     UCSR0B|=(1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXEN0);                     //enable receiver and transmitter
     UCSR0C|=(1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<UCSZ01);// 8bit data format
 }

 // function to send data - NOT REQUIRED FOR THIS PROGRAM IMPLEMENTATION
 void uart_transmit (unsigned char data)
 {
     while (!( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));                  // wait while register is free
     UDR0 = data;                                                     // load data in the register
 }

 // function to receive data
 unsigned char uart_recieve (void)
 {
     while(!(UCSR0A) & (1<<RXC0));                     // wait while data is being received
     return UDR0;                                                     // return 8-bit data
 }

 // main function: entry point of program
 int main (void)
 {
     unsigned char a;
     char buffer[10];

     uart_init();                                                    // initialize UART

     while(1)
     {

         uart_transmit( uart_recieve());                               

         _delay_ms(100);                                         
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have missing parentheses in `while(!(UCSR0A) & (1<<RXC0));` condition. Correct it as

`while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));`

or

`while(!(UCSR0A & _BV(RXC0)));`

to reuse macros or

`while(!bitRead(UCSR0A, RXC0));`

if using *Arduino.h* library.